# asp.net authentication - use credentials from web.config - problem

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I have a simple problem which is giving me headaches for a couple of days.

I've created very simple application with login control. I keep user data in web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".RzeskoLoginCookie">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
             <user name="test" password="test"/>
        </credentials>
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

I will deploy this simple website to IIS on computer on which I do not want to use SQL Server.

My login button event looks like this:

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
    }
}
```

Now the problem:

When I am running a website on VS2008 built in webserver, everything works fine (I can log in). When I copy my website to IIS I am constantly getting this annoying error (after I click Login button):

> Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to failure in
>   retrieving the user's local
>   application data path. Please make
>   sure the user has a local user profile
>   on the computer. The connection will
>   be closed.

I also observed that in my App_Data folder some weird files are being created.

To sum up. What I want to achieve is to use user credentials from web.config file, without using sql server.

I'd appreciate any help

Kind Regards
PK

Answer (score 4):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx) page for Login control:

*

> The Login control uses a membership
>   provider to obtain user credentials.
>   Unless you specify otherwise, the
>   Login control uses the default
>   membership provider defined in the
>   Web.config file. To specify a
>   different provider, set the
>   MembershipProvider property to one of
>   the membership provider names defined
>   in your application's Web.config file.
>   For more information, see Membership
>   Providers.

*

The default Membership provider is the **AspNetSqlProvider** which uses a SQL Server database as its user store.

If you want to provide a custom authentication routine, you can either write your own custom Membership provider or handle the [OnAuthenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onauthenticate.aspx) method of the Login control to provide your own authentication logic.

Comment: Then why on the test server everything works? User credentials are read from web.config?

Comment: But what provider do you specify to get it to use the credentials in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

If you notice in your code, you have the method declaration for handling the `<asp:Login>` control's LoggingIn event:

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
```

This control interfaces with the ASP.NET Membership provider which is probably why it is looking for a connection string.

So rather than using the `<asp:Login>` control, simply use a button and handle the `Click` event so that there is no use of Membership:

```
<asp:Button id="LoginButton" Text="Login" OnClick="Login_OnClick" runat="server" />
```

Code behind (notice the different signature of the method):

```
public void Login_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works on the visual development server, but i still have the same error when publishing in IIS...It still tries to use the default membership and the sqlprovider (and connect to sql database), even if i use an my own event like you do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everybody for pointing out the solution.
I finally managed to avoid that error by creating my own authentication event (associated with the login control).