# Using Forms Authentication without .Net providers

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I want to protect a section of my website using forms authentication with the username and password as defined by me in the web.config. When I attempt to login I get the message below.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
```

I'm guessing this is happening because it's attempting to use the Membership tables as defined by the LocalSqlServer connection string. **I don't want to use the Membership features**, how do I configure my web app to do that?

Will I need to write the Authenticate function myself for the in-built Login control?

Comment: Hi, have you already used the asp.net SQL Server setup tool?
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/25/423703.aspx

Comment: That's precisely what I don't want to use. Let me re-iterate, I don't want to use the Membership features.

Comment: Another very similar question with a different answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583262/asp-net-authentication-use-credentials-from-web-config-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with your config file, it's with the Login control.

The Login control uses the default Membership Provider that is defined in the machine.config. (It's a SqlMembershipProvider that points to a SQL Express database).

You don't want to use the default Membership Provider at all. Simply create your own login page and use the following server-side logic to validate the credentials and log the user into the site:

```
    if( Page.IsValid )
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtName.Text,txtPassword.Text)) 
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtName.Text, false);
        else
            lblMsg1.Text = "Wrong name or password. Please try again.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx">
    <credentials>
      <user name="Joe" password="Smith" />
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: I'm aware of this and this setup already. My application is attempting to access SQL even though I've defined my config in the way you have described.

Comment: what about your membership entry into your .config?

Comment: I have no membership entry defined in my web.config