# Forms authentication: how do you store username password in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm used to using Forms Authentication with a database, but I'm writing a little internal utility and the app doesn't have a database so I want to store the username and password in web.config.  However for some reason, forms authentication is still trying to access SQL Server and I can't see how to stop it doing this and pick up the credentials from web.config. What am I doing wrong?  I just get the error "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in impersonating the client. The connection will be closed."

Here are the relevant sections of my web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="60" name=".LoginCookie" path="/"  >
                <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                    <user name="user1" password="[pass]" />
                    <user name="user2" password="[pass]" />
                </credentials>
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: [Encrypt and store password in web.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356537/encrypt-and-store-password-in-web-config-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) is the  [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which will try to use a SqlServer database.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583262/asp-net-authentication-use-credentials-from-web-config-problem) similar question.